Book series with two male protagonists, one embodying the moon and the other the sun
This is going to be vague as I haven't read the books in several years. They came out the late 70s or 80s.
The series was, as best as I can recall, set in a medieval time frame and had 2 male leads. One male embodied the power of the moon and the waning house, while his friend embodied the power of the sun and the power waxing. The one who embodied the moon could trace his lineage to the elves. Both married elven females.
That is about all I can remember.

What language, what book format, published where, any memories of the covers?  Please edit your answers into the question; the information will improve the quality of answers you might receive.

The Silver Sun by Nancy Springer. One of the young men was the son of the evil ruler, and was part elven on his mother's side. The other one was his half brother by a lord's wife. The half-elf (Hal) married a human girl, and his brother (Alan) married an elf. They ruled together as co-kings; wearing silver and gold crowns respectively. It's the second book in the "Book of Isle" series.
